# Custom enumerate format in Curve CV class

Tags: enumerate, curve-class

I am using this template from overleaf to build my CV, which uses the Curve CV class
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv

Now, there is a section "Research Publication" that uses `biblatex` and `printbibliography` to directly list all the publication in numbered fashion.

[image]

However, I want to fill this section manually with the `enumerate` environment, but that gives a pretty simple numbered list like this

[image]

How can I use the `enumerate` environment and still have the list numbering format from the original one (i.e., number within the red filled circle)? What are the changes I have to made to the enumerate items?